# Интересный вопрос про относительные ссылки

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ссылки, mod-rewrite

Использую на сайте паттерн MVC, соответственно mod_rewritом все запросы перенаправляю на index.php, при этом URLы имеют вид

```
    www.site.ru/razdel/podrazdel
```

Используя относительные ссылки все работает корректно, используя путь от начальной директории:

```
    /папка/файл
```

но только если URL будут такими:

```
    www.site.ru или www.site.ru/razdel
```

при этом с таким URL

```
    www.site.ru/razdel/podrazdel
```

что бы работали относительные ссылки нужно спускаться на один каталог ниже т.е.

```
    ../папка/файл
```

Хотелось бы разобраться почему так, ведь все запросы идут на index.php в котором и подключаются остальные файлы. 
P.S. Мне не нужны "обходные" пути решения проблемы, хочется именно разобраться почему так работает...

В дополнение для более четкой картины логика приложения:
Запросы направляются на index.php, в зависимости от URL маршрутизатором загружаем нужный контроллер.
Для www.site.ru/razdel используем controller + action1 который подключает основной шаблон + шаблон для конкретного раздела
Для www.site.ru/razdel/podrazdel (раздел идентичен первому примеру) подключаем тот же controller + action2 который подключает основной шаблон + шаблон для конкретного подраздела...

Похоже не поняли вопрос, объясню в другом формате:
Заходим на site.ru или на site.ru/razdel
При использовании относительных ссылок все работает правильно: 
Например загрузка css используем ссылку href="css/style.css" , получаем:

```
    site.ru/css/style.css
```

Заходим на site.ru/razdel/podrazdel
Используем ссылку href="css/style.css" , получаем:

```
    site.ru/razdel/css/style.css
```

Но такого пути нету, нужен как в первом варианте:

```
    site.ru/css/style.css
```

Вопрос в том, почему он начинает путь с razdel а не с корневой директории?
Код htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(jpg|gif|swf|ico)$ index.php [NC,L]
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: объясните на конкретном примере, что  у вас работает на `site.ru` и не работает на `www.site.ru` без каких-то `папка/файл`, а с конкретикой, и что приходит в `index.php` для обоих случаев, и если упомянули `mod_rewrite` то код `.htaccess` в студию.

Comment: Не понял причем тут site.ru и www.site.ru
Остальное дополню в посте

Comment: извиняюсь, прочитал криво. показлось что у вас на `site.ru` работает, а на `www.site` нет.

Comment: дак используйте абсолютный путь `/css/style.css` да и все, зачем вы его вообще относительным пишите?

Comment: А <base> установлен у вас?

Comment: Да, пробовал и с base и без...